# Why is my desktop background black?

Tags: windows, desktop

I have got Windows 8 x64. It is a lot of time I have this laptop [like three years so far] and I have never run into what happened to me this morning. I had a photo like desktop background. I have never had any problems with this laptop. This morning for the first time as soon as I logged on, the desktop was black. On the main menu there was the usual window and I could see clearly the real background but once I was logged in, the background was completely black and I did wait for the PC to load but nothing changed.
I had to choose again the picture for the desktop background. 
What has happened?! I have got no viruses, no untrustworthy .exe installed, nothing.

Comment: check  this http://winaero.com/blog/bug-desktop-turns-black-in-windows-8-1/

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when your Windows Activation is no longer valid. It can occur for several reasons: the Window's license code was used on multiple devices, the license key was temporary and has expired, the file where the key is stored has been corrupted or deleted, etc.

Comment: I DO know that. It happened to me two years ago when I downloaded Windows 7 off the internet and 'removed' the Product ID so Windows would have not lasted only 30 days. That is a different matter.
Anyway, suddenly, the problem has been solved after I ticked off 'Adjust Windows for best performance' in Performance Options.